# How to get minimum target framework from csproj in .netcore 5

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I retrieve the minimum target framework (as defined in the .csproj file at runtime in c#?

I making a wpf app in Dotnet core 5. I am using some Microsoft toolkit APIs, which requires a minimum target. I set my app target to (10.0.20348.0), but need to make sure that the user has windows 10 build 19041 at a minimum.

Using reflection and assembly attributes, I can only find the target, but not the minimum.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure of the win build number at build time or runtime? At runtime you can use 'Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build'

Comment: Yes, this returns the current systems built version, but  I am looking to get the app/project minimum build target dynamically instead of harding coding it into a parameter. I technically could , but that becomes multiple parameters to manage for the same item. Not sure if I am thinking about it the right way...